# Trying to troubleshoot concatenating a string in C

Tags: c, debugging

I am trying to concatenate two strings together. I put two strings into two arrays and created a third array that is the size of the two strings. Then I use the for loop to print out one letter at a time.

The program gets to `This` before crashing. There are no error codes or debug messages in the IDE!!! How do I debug my program and what kind of mindset should I have if I have no obvious error messages to go off of when something like this happens?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int pointerArrays() {
    char strOne[] = {"This is the first string array."};
    char strTwo[] = {"This is the second string array."};

    char *px, *py, *pz;
    px = strOne;
    py = strTwo;
    pz = (char *) malloc(1 + sizeof(px) + sizeof(py));
    strcpy(pz, px);
    strcpy(pz, py);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pz); i++) {
        printf("%c", pz[i]);
    }
    return 0;


}

int main(void) {

    pointerArrays();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Never use sizeof to get the sting lengt sizeof is used to get size of the objects and types.

Comment: 2. Always check the result of malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. First of all, this here doesn't work:

```
malloc(1 + sizeof(px) + sizeof(py));
```

`sizeof(px)` doesn't evaluate to the size of the string, it just evaluates to the size of a `char*`, which isn't what you intended. Instead, try something like this:

```
pz = (char *)malloc(strlen(strOne) + strlen(strTwo) + 1);
```

The second problem is that instead of concatenating the two strings, you're copying them over each other. The second call needs to be

```
strcat(pz, py);
```

Rather than `strcpy` again.

On a side note, when you print a string, instead of just looping through the array, you can also just use the `%s` format specifier:

```
printf("%s", pz);
```

Last but not least, don't forget to free the memory when you're done:

```
free(pz);
```

Comment: Okay cool, thanks for the comments. Regarding the `free(pz);`, should this be inserted when I am done using the pointer, or outside of the function?

Comment: You can do the `free(pz);` as soon as you don't need the memory anymore. In your program, you don't need it anymore after the `printf`, so you can put it there (which is rightthe return anyway). In this small program the lack of a `free` shouldn't be a problem because the program terminates shortly after and then the OS cleans it up anyway, but it's good to get in the habit.

Answer (score 2):

*Just a sidenote (not the reason of your crash): you are copying to the same location twice:*

```
    strcpy(pz, px);
    strcpy(pz, py);
```

should be

```
    strcpy(pz, px);
    strcpy(pz + strlen(px), py);
```

*not fixing it would cause y to right OVER x*

But the main issue is using sizeof instead of strlen. sizeof will return the pointer's size (4 or 8 typically), while strlen will actually return the length of the string (which is what you expected)

Comment: OP could also use `snprintf` for a one line instruction.

Answer (score 2):

Insert another line to see what the argument to `malloc()` rceives:

```
printf ("malloc(%d)\n", 1 + sizeof(px) + sizeof(py));
```

I bet you can figure it out from there.

Comment: ahh that makes more sense. I suppose in the future, I can use print statements to isolate where I think the problem might be

Comment: @EvanKim good debug practice - try to narrow the field using prints :)

Answer (score 0):

using sizeof is very dangerous and will fail in most real life usage cases.

it is enough to change

```
char strOne[] = "This is the first string array.";
char strTwo[] = "This is the second string array.";
```

to

```
char strOne[64] = "This is the first string array.";
char strTwo[64] = "This is the second string array.";
```

or

```
char *strOne = "This is the first string array.";
char *strTwo = "This is the second string array.";
```

and the result of your function will be far from the expected.

**Always** use strlen to get the string length.

Here you have much more universal and safer solution:

char *concatenate(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    size_t str1len = strlen(str1), str2len = strlen(str2);

```
char *res = malloc(str1len + str2len + 1);

if(res)
{
    strcpy(res, str1);
    strcpy(res + str1len, str2);
}
return res;
```

}

Comment: *"it is enough to change "* Neither of those fixes the problem. Problem is not the sizeof, but the variable type given to it.

Comment: @user694733 read the rest of my post. : **and the result of your function will be far from the expected.**  So it is not the solution but example when problems arise

Comment: Ah you edited it. But still, types of `strOne` and `strTwo` not the problem, because they are not given to `sizeof`. Your solution seems ok though.